# Disable the ttk button resizeing

Tags: python, tkinter, ttkwidgets

Is there a way to disable the resize of a ttk Button? So that I can maximaze the text inside the button.

I tried to set the size of the buttons with config(width, height) which didn't work, so I used ipadx and ipady. But the button size is not fixed permanently and changes when the text size is changed.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the way is to put the `ttk.Button` inside a frame with specified `width` and `height` in pixels and make the button to fill the frame:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
root.config(padx=10, pady=10)

s = ttk.Style()
s.configure("my.TButton", font=("", 28)) # set the font size to whatever you like

### ttk.Button put inside a frame with specified width and height in pixels
frame = ttk.Frame(root, width=200, height=50)
frame.pack()

btn = ttk.Button(frame, text="Hello World", style="my.TButton")
# make the button to fill the parent frame
btn.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

### ttk.Button without using frame
ttk.Button(root, text="Hello World", style="my.TButton").pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Output:

[image]